# Multithreaded calculation in excel is slow

Tags: multithreading, performance, excel, architecture

I'm wondering if there is any way to control excel calculation such that several sheets in a WB are recalculated in parallel, while the others not.  My problem is that under the current set up the sequential calculation process i have is taking too long.  The sequence is driven from VBA and goes something like this:
1) vba calls an addin (excel-dna vb.net addin, that controls a datareader and attached database)
2) addin returns data to sheet 1.  Sheets 2-3 are recalculated in sequence (sheet 2, then 3)
3) sheets 4 through 10 are recalculated in sequence, but since each independently only links to sheet 2, they could in theory recalculate in parallel - right?  But how to do this?
4) begin process again with calling of new data via vba addin described in 1)

Running a subset of data on my laptop (64bit with 32bit excel, intel i7) it takes 54.6 seconds.  Interestingly, if i switch off multithreading, it takes 25.8 seconds!  What's more if i run it on a super fast machine (2 x Intel Xeon X5570, quad-core “Nehalem” architecture, 64bit with 64bit excel) it's slower than my laptop, taking 230seconds with multithreading or 26 seconds without.

I wonder if there is a better way i might make use of the multiple cores and multithreading.  The slow bit appears to be excel recalculation rather than the addin speed.  Any suggestions appreciated.

edit:
The above description is a bit of a simplification - In actuality, i also have an iterative 'calc/paste-vales/recalc' process that runs on each of sheets 4-10 (the iteration proceeds until some required sensitivity is reached, and only then is the full sheet calculated).  I believe this makes running a wb calculate under the current design unworkable.

Sheets 4-10 are identical (except for hard-coded input parameters) and have no calculation dependencies between one another.  If the calculation process (mentioned iteration procedure and sheet calc) of each could be done in parallel instead of sequentially, i think the total process would be much faster.

FYI, i already performed the more obvious streamlining and testing (breaking up formulas, separating volatile functions etc).

Running my entire data set through the process as it stands takes about 16 hours, which is why i'm keen to find some ways to improve on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- Here's a great start to reading about Excel calculation performance: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm.
- You can mark an Excel-DNA function as thread-safe using an attribute like [ExcelFunction(IsThreadSafe=true)], though that doesn't sound like the bottleneck here. That will allow these functions to be evaluated concurrently.
- If your i7 processor has hyper-threading (so it reports 4 cores to Windows but actually has only two real cores), then it can be faster to set the Excel number of threads to the number of cores (say 2) instead of the number of threads the processor can run (which would be the Excel default - maybe 4).

Comment: Hi Govert.  The excel-dna and dotnet datareader aspects of this seem pretty efficient.  In any case i ran micro-timed tests on a subset of data, based on your suggestions:
Multi-threading off (28.3); On + 1 thread (30.3); On + 2 threads (70.8); all available processors (65.1).  Switching IsExceptionSafe=True and IsThreadSafe=True made no noticeable difference (both false and both true both timed at 28.3sec).  I wonder if, if the recalc command for each sheet was sent from an excel-dna addin if it might somehow become faster?  eg vba runs excel-dna addin that then sends sheet recalc commands.

Comment: There are some recent performance discussions and results related to Excel-DNA here: http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_frm/thread/e331337fcdc22a17. This seems to indicate that calling the sheet calculate via COM and via the C API does not make a difference.

Comment: thanks.  re the earlier discussion.  I only just noticed that the results generate with Threadsafe:=True and multi-threaded calculation yielded spurious results.  I guess my app isn't thread safe afterall...

Answer (score 1):

Its very unusual for multi-threaded calculation to be slower than single-threaded calculation.

Presumably you have switched calculation to Manual.

Are you using Sheet.Calculate on each sheet to "calculate the worksheets in sequence"? If so it would probably be faster to just use Application.Calculate and let Excel automagically work out the fastest way to recalculate all the sheets.

Comment: Hi Charles,  I've read your blogs on calculation speed and have some use of your work in the past.  Thank you.

You're correct - I have calculation set to manual and control the calculation order from VBA; call excel-dna addin that loads data into first sheet, then calc subsequent sheets sequentially; sheets("Sheet2").calculate, sheets("Sheet3").calculate, etc.  
Please see my edit above which gives some more detail.

Comment: Why not iterate all sheets 4-10 at the same time?

Comment: Yes I would very much like to iterate/calculate sheets 4-10 at the same time (=in parallel).  But I'm not aware how this is possible unless i run separate instances of excel.  Interested to hear of another way if you know of one - this would really get to the essence of my question.

Comment: So - calc all sheets using Application.Calculate (which will multi-thread), paste values on each of sheets 4-10, and repeat until all sheets have converged. By the way, in case you are using Range.Calculate note that it is NOT multithreaded

Comment: i like your suggestion but unfortunately the feeder sheets (1-3) have some heavy calculations on them including volatile formulas, so each application.calculate will be hit by that overhead.  That said, you've given me some ideas worth investigating further and i might see if i can work around the overhead issue.  re range.calculate; yes i read that thanks (maybe i read it on your site) and found in practice it was slower so have stuck with worksheet.calculate.   what a pity there is nothing like; worksheets(4-10).calculate!

Comment: so switch off the feeder sheets by setting their worksheet.enablecalculation to false

Comment: I didn't know of that function.  Useful.  My tests however show that using this was still much slower than the original single threaded sheet-by-sheet version. The only explanation that comes to mind is that there is some overhead involved when i switch worksheet.enablecalculation off and then on (for sheets 1-3), before and after each application.calculate cycle (=> multi-threaded calc of sheets 4-10).  Is it possible that this disable/enable action causes excel into a rebuild of the calculation map?

Comment: It seems we ae miscommunicating: my suggestion was to switch OFF sheets 1 to 3 and iterate all the remaining sheets simultaneously using application.calculate until they have all converged, then switch ON sheets 1-3

Comment: i believe we're on the same wavelength, but maybe i didn't explain completely.  I have an outer loop puts new data into sheets 1-3 (via udf calls triggered by calculation of those sheets) and then calculates the inner loop (sheets 4-10 iteration and recalc).  so switching off sheets 1-3 once before each inner loop, and then back on again before each outer loop, maybe means some overhead (?) -  I have 11 million data cycles to perform on the outer loop, so that's a lot of switching on and off.  NB: some of the sheet 1-3 udfs are marked volatile.