# Multi-threaded calculation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

My Excel is 2019 Professional version and Under "Advance"---"Formulas", chose "Enable multi-Threaded calculation" and "use all processors on this computer:16 ". My CPU is Intel I7-11700 that has 16 threads.

While running VBA, CPU usage is around 13-16% only. Thus, one thread is fully used and the other 2 threads were used from time to time.

**How could I change the setting to utilize the CPU more?** (i.e. at least 75-80% of CPU or at least 12 threads at the same time?)

If I use old generation of the CPU (i.e. 8th ) with the same Excel file, VBA codes and Excel version, I found that all CPU threads were used.

Comment: VBA does not support multi-threading from what I can find. What I'd suggest for maximum CPU usage would be to turn off Auto-Calculation at the beginning of your VBA then re-enable it at the end, if possible based on your code. This way your VBA will run faster and then use all 16 threads when it exits to recalculate the workbook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903520/multithreaded-calculation-in-excel-is-slow

Comment: `Under "Advance"---"Formulas"` - correct. That applies only to formulas.

Comment: https://excel-dna.net/ allows you to develop extensions (like worksheet functions) with multi-thread support, as far as I know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721564/multi-threading-in-vba

Comment: Dear all Experts
Thanks for your reply/help.

However, if I used old generation of the CPU (i.e 8th )  with the same Excel file ,VBA codes and same excel version, I found that all CPU threads were used.  ----Why? Could you all please explain it?

Comment: Please help further